# fill matplotlib pie chart sectors with my string labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart

as
to_show=['A','B','C','D','E']
hello i want to fill the sectors of pie chart with some string values like A,B,C,D,E
autopct is a function for this but i don't know the exact method for showing in the sectors of pie chart and hide the automatic made %ages values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # make the pie circular by setting the aspect ratio to 1 
plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(1)) 
index = [1, 2, 3, 4] 
values = [1, 2, 3, 4] 
labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] 
cutom_labels = ['1', '2,3', '4,5', '6']

num = -1  
 
plt.pie(values, labels=cutom_labels,labeldistance=0.5) 
plt.pie(values, labels=labels) 
plt.show()`
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not getting your question but we use autopct to show %area

if u don't want %ages just remove autopct

refer [documanetation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_features.html) hope it will help

Comment: when you run the code  in all the sectors it gives same values.
what i want is to change the values in every sector according to the cutom_labels

`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# make the pie circular by setting the aspect ratio to 1
plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(1))
index = [1, 2, 3, 4]
values = [1, 2, 3, 4]
labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
cutom_labels = ['1', '2,3', '4,5', '6']
num = -1

def make_autopct(values):

    def my_autopct(pct):
        return cutom_labels[2]

    return my_autopct


plt.pie(values, labels=labels, autopct=make_autopct(values))
plt.show()`

Comment: please run the code i provided in comment section

Comment: thankyou for the answer
 i ran the above  code of you
 it worked for me